# How to sort column data bottom to top

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

When I add a data to my database, the newest data should be printed first.

I have tried descending sorting method to sort database data

```
void DECS()
{
    con.Open();

    string query = "SELECT ID, ODate, DDate, Name, Amount, Status, Requirement, WatchIDs, Cwatchers FROM BuyerInfo ORDER BY ID, ODate, DDate, Name, Amount, Status, Requirement, WatchIDs, Cwatchers DESC ";

    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);
    SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

I use above code to descending database details. But it didn't do anything.

Comment: What column(s) determine what data is "newest?"  Sample data would help greatly here.

Comment: `DESC` needs to be specified against the column(s) you **specifically** want in descending order. Likely after `ID`, or possibly after **all** columns in your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: You are sorting all columns in ascending order but the last one in descending order. You have another field that uniquely should impose an order of insertion. It is the ID if you have it as an IDENTITY

Comment: `ORDER BY ID DESC`

Comment: ``` {
            con.Open();

            string query = "SELECT ID,ODate,DDate,Name,Amount,Status,Requirement,WatchIDs,Cwatchers FROM BuyerInfo ORDER BY ID DESC ";
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);
            SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
 ```       }

Comment: i use above code. but it didn't do anything

Comment: You mean the code in your question didn't do anything? You called `ExecuteNonQuery`  which runs the SQL but doesn't expect, or return, the output. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query from this :

```
string query = "SELECT ID, ODate, DDate, Name, Amount, Status, Requirement, WatchIDs, Cwatchers FROM BuyerInfo ORDER BY ID, ODate, DDate, Name, Amount, Status, Requirement, WatchIDs, Cwatchers DESC ";
```

into this :

```
string query = "SELECT ID, ODate, DDate, Name, Amount, Status, Requirement, WatchIDs, Cwatchers FROM BuyerInfo ORDER BY DDate DESC ";
```